# How to Visualize attention weights in a Attention based Encoder-Decoder network in Time series forecasting

Tags: deep-learning, time-series, forecasting, attention-mechanism, encoder

Below is one example Attention-based Encoder-decoder network for multivariate time series forecasting task. I want to visualize the attention weights.

```
input_ = Input(shape=(TIME_STEPS,N))
x = attention_block(input_)
x = LSTM(512, return_sequences=True)(x)
x = LSTM(512)(x)
x = RepeatVector(n_future)(x)
x = LSTM(128, activation='relu', return_sequences=True)(x)
x = TimeDistributed(Dense(128, activation='relu'))(x)
x = Dense(1)(x)
model = Model(input_,x)
model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error",optimizer="adam",metrics=["acc"])
print(model.summary())
```

Here is the implementation of my attention block:

```
def attention_block(inputs):
    x=Permute((2,1))(inputs)
    x=Dense(TIME_STEPS,activation="softmax")(x)
    x=Permute((2,1),name="attention_prob")(x)
    x=multiply([inputs,x])
return x
```

I will highly appreciate if a fresh implementation of the attention model is provided.

Answer (score 1):

A reference: *https://github.com/zhaocq-nlp/Attention-Visualization/blob/master/exec/plot_heatmap.py*. It plots attentions based on `matplotlib`

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/80026)

Comment: I need the attention values, i.e. the probability values, and if you have any example of time series forecasting, that helps. Thank you.